# Mysql insert query complains >= not valid at this position error

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I used to run a mysql query for inserting data in db and everything used to work fine. I am now same query after few months and it gives an error that:

```
>= is not valid at this position, expecting : EOF, ';'
```

Below is the sql query I am trying to run and I get an error near

> `start_time` >= 36000000

```
INSERT INTO `expert_slots` (`expert_id`, `slot_id`, `is_active`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) 
SELECT 449 as `expert_id`, id as `slot_id`, 1 as `is_active`, 
unix_timestamp(now())*1000 as `created_at`, unix_timestamp(now())*1000 as `updated_at` 
FROM slots WHERE `start_time` >= 36000000 and end_time <= 68400000 and day in ('MON', 'TUE', 'WED', 'THU', 'FRI');
```

Can anyone help me understand what is the error here ?

I am running the code in mysql workbench

Comment: This error does not come from mysql. try executing the query!

Comment: Your code works fine:  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fQWnYvrdHTc42wFU1zpzmU/0

Comment: I also tested the query you post above. It does not return the error you say it does. Perhaps the error is coming from a different query?

Comment: That doesn't look like a MySQL error message. They usually say something like "Syntax error near ...". It looks like something that comes from an IDE.